Java Auth-JWT application with spring-boot and swagger
I actually have a issue in my java auth spring-boot project.
I have to make an auth registration with token for a project and to do that I found a github repository who makes what a want.
This is the github repository :
https://github.com/ninvit/spring-jwt-swagger/tree/main/src/main
But the thing is when I copy everything into my project but now I have some issue with 2 specific files :
"JwtTokenFilter.java" and  "JwtTokenFilterConfigurer.java"
this is the issue that I have :
"security/JwtTokenFilter.java":
Class 'JwtTokenFilter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain)' in 'OncePerRequestFilter'
And
Method does not override method from its superclass
"security/JwtTokenFilterConfigurer.java" :
'addFilterBefore(javax.servlet.Filter, java.lang.Class<? extends javax.servlet.Filter>)' in 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' cannot be applied to '(com.paris13.dev.security.JwtTokenFilter, java.lang.Class<org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>)'
Resolve my problem.

what version of spring are you using
